# JavaScript AVL Tree - delete node with children

Tags: javascript, recursion, avl-tree

I am implementing FAST way of managing AVL Tree in JavaScript:
The creation of a balanced tree was easy, however, deleting of a node seems issue:

I looked for clear explanation of AVL node deletion, and found plenty of explanation deleting LEAF node. My concern: **What if I want to delete node from the middle?**

My approach is:

```
// n is the node to be deleted
// each node has "k" property which is the key which sorting is done based on.

if(n.parent) {
    if(n.parent.k>n.k) { // we are the left side of parent
        // link the biggest value (right) to parent:
        n.parent.left=n.right||n.left; // but if has no n.right, than take n.left
        n.right.parent=n.parent; // link the parent to that child
    }
    else {
        // do the same to the other side (just opposite)
        n.parent.right=n.left||n.right; n.left.parent=n.parent;
    }
}
else { // if no parent, then n is root
    this.db=n.right||n.left; // put the right child as root, or the left one if the right is missing.
    if(n.right) { delete n.right.parent; if(n.left) n.left.parent=n.right; } // update link
    else if(n.left) delete n.left.parent;
}

// !!! balancing???!!!
```

**Issues:**

1. Deleting from the leaf is easy, but requires balancing as well. Deleting from the center of the tree requires even more balancing, but I have no clue how to begin at this point... Considering making del() recursive...
2. If I would make del() recursive, will I need to just "pull up" all the nodes till I reach the leaf one and then remove? My concern is that this operation is time consuming, and maybe wrong, unless NO OTHER way to go.

**NOTE:** I am NOT keeping balance factor in the nodes, as this requires constant update, and I found in JS calling a function like gH is much faster - Tested 100000 records took it 15 seconds with balance factor and 0.9 seconds with function getHeight() - I have no idea why.

**CORRECTION:**
The above approach is wrong, and I found that need to loop thru the nodes up to the leaf and replace "deleting" node with the leaf one - yet remaining to build up this algorithm. My understanding that the balancing starts in the leaf node upward, but maybe I am wrong... As far as I understand I should not stop recursion in the "deleted node", but go up to the root...

**General implementation code:**

```
// Rotations
function rotateLeft(a) {
    var n=a.right; a.right=n.left; a.right.parent=a; n.left=a; return n;
}
function rotateRight(a) {
    var n=a.left; a.left=n.right; a.left.parent=a; n.right=a; return n;
}
function rotateLeftRight(a) {
    a.right=rotateLeft(a.right);
    return rotateRight(a);
}
function rotateRightLeft(a) {
    a.left=rotateRight(a.left);
    return rotateLeft(a);
}

// Get tree height at specific node
function getHeight(n) {
    if(!n) return 0;
    var l=getHeight(n.left),r=getHeight(n.right);
    return (l>r?l:r)+1;
}

// Do balancing as per situation:
function bal(n) {
    if(!n) return; var b=getHeight(n.left),e=getHeight(n.right);
    if(b-e>1) 
        return (getHeight(n.left.left)>=getHeight(n.left.right)?rotateRight(n):rotateRightLeft(n));
    if(e-b>1)
        return (getHeight(n.right.right)>=getHeight(n.right.left)?rotateLeft(n):rotateLeftRight(n));
    return n;
}

// Add single node
this.add=function(v,n) {
    // v = single node data. contents permited:
    //      k = key (based on which will do sorting)
    //      v = internal value (optional)
    if(!this.db) { this.db=v; return; } if(!n) n=this.db;
    if(v.k<n.k)
        if(!n.left) { v.parent=n; n.left=v; n.left=bal(n.left); }
        else this.add(v,n.left);
    else
        if(!n.right) { v.parent=n; n.right=v; n.right=bal(n.right); }
        else this.add(v,n.right);
};

// And the problem comming:
this.del=function(n) { ... }
```

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: `Element.remove()` should remove the Element and its children.

Comment: Imagine the tree represents a big data table. I prefer to not remove the entire node with its children, rather remove the node unit alone, pulling up its children, or I will accidently remove more than what I want...

Comment: This code is extremely difficult to read, making it hard to assist. I recommend adding vertical and horizontal whitespace to your code. Variable names should be descriptive, not one or two letter abbreviations. If you feel the need to say "`p` is a parent pointer" in a comment, you could just call `p` as `parent` throughout the code and save readers the indirection.

Comment: @ggorlen using long names is highly debatable. long var names make code length explode, make it impossible to follow it *visually*. one-letter var names with good comments at point of introduction is a valid style choice. white space, yes, by all means. again, to easier follow the code *visually.* I even advocate aligning *vertically* the related stuff on separate lines of code, with some extra whitespace as needed.